# How to take two database backup in a single operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can anyone please help me to take two database backups in a single operation of database backuping in Sql Server 2005.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see
 http://sqlbackupandftp.com/

Comment: @Arun always welcome D:)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? This is a db-script that backs up two databases.

```
DECLARE @database1 varchar(100)
DECLARE @database2 varchar(100)
DECLARE @backupDir1 varchar(500)
DECLARE @backupDir2 varchar(500)

SET @database1 = 'NameOfdb1'
SET @database2 = 'NameOfdb2'
SET @backupDir1 = 'C:\Inetpub\db_backup\' + @database1
SET @backupDir2 = 'C:\Inetpub\db_backup\' + @database2

BACKUP DATABASE @database1
TO DISK = @backupDir1
WITH STATS = 10

BACKUP DATABASE @database2
TO DISK = @backupDir2
WITH STATS = 10
```

I put this in a StoredProcedure, and can then run it as one operation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below blog

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-backup-pro-for-the-accidental-dba/